# Dynamic Program to solve an NP-complete partitioning problem

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, np-complete, dynamic-programming, efficiency

I have this problem for which I am struggling to find an efficient dynamic programming algorithm. Would be thankful for some help!!

Let $A = \{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \}$ be a set where $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for $i=1,...,n$.

The goal is to determine whether there exist two disjoint subsets $M,N \subset A$ such that the sum of all elements in $M$ is equal to exactly *$\textit{twice}$* the sum of all elements in $N,$ and $M \not = \emptyset$ and $N \not = \emptyset.$

Comment: Let $t$ be the sum of all input values. I think your best bet will be an $O(nt^2)$-time, $O(t^2)$-space algorithm that generalises the usual Knapsack algorithm by looping through all items in some order, and generating all *pairs* of sums that can be formed from the first $i$ elements -- by adding the $i$-th item to either element of all *pairs* of sums $(a, b)$ that can be formed from the first $i-1$ items. At the end, look for pairs of the form $(a, 2a)$. This is only pseudopolynomial time, but I'm certain ordinary Knapsack can be reduced to this.

Comment: Ins't the answer trivially yes? Pick $M=N=\emptyset$.

Comment: That's my bad, both $M$ and $N$ must not be empty. Will add that in now.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sigma(S)$ denote the sum of all the elements in $S$ and $A_i = \{a_1, \dots, a_i\}$.

Given, $i=0,\dots,n$ and $w \in \mathbb{Z}$, 
define $OPT[i,w]$ as the mazimum cardinality of a subset $S \cup S' \subseteq A_i$ where $S \cap S' = \emptyset$
and $\sigma(S) - 2\sigma(S') = w$.
If no possible choice for $S$ and $S'$ exists, then let $OPT[i,w]=-\infty$.

According to the above definition:
$$
OPT[0, w] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } w=0 \\
-\infty & \text{if } w \neq 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

For $i>0$:
$$
    OPT[i, w] = \max\{ OPT[i-1, w], 1 + OPT[i-1, w-a_i], 1+ OPT[i-1, w+2a_i] \}.
$$

The answer to your problem is true iff $OPT[n, 0] > 0$.
Each $OPT[i, w]$ can be computed in constant time (if you have already computed the values of $OPT[i-1, \cdot]$).
Moreover, there are only $O(n)$ possible choices for $i$ and $O(t)$ sensible choices for $w$, where $t = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.
This gives you a dynamic programming algorithm with time complexity $O(n t)$ and space complexity $O(t)$.

Comment: That checks out!! Thanks a lot for the answer, appreciate it!!

Comment: Nice answer! You could use a single bit for each $OPT[i,w]$, and set a global "solution exists" flag when some $OPT[i, 0]$ can be achieved from some $OPT[i-1, x]$ with $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, yep! My first write up used one bit per $OPT[i,w]$ but then I had the problem that $N=M=\emptyset$ would always be a solution. I thought of keeping two bits per $OPT[i,w]$ ("is there a solution?" and "is there a non-trivial solution?") but it felt "hacky" so I looked for a "natural" subproblem definition that would circumvent the problem altogether.